# Best place to load async all data

Tags: swift, collectionview

I am transforming a stackView into a collectionView.
I have big problems with reusing cells on collectionView.

**CollectionView** has a **ContainerCell**. Depending on a model property like type, I have there a different view inserted (on container's contentView).

My real problem is that in the **ContainerCell** I have an async call to ws, and this one fills the according view with data.
Also, every view needs sometimes more data from the web service.

```
 class ContainerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     var widget: SmallWidget!

     func refresh(_ completion: @escaping () -> () = {}) {
        ....

         WidgetsService().runOneDashboard(widgetDashboardId: widget.model.widgetDashboardId) {[unowned self] result in
         if self.widget != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.widget.fillForms(dictionary: result)
                widget.activityIndicator.stop()
                completion()
            }
        }
    }

      private func addWidgetToView(_ widget: SmallWidget) {
          customContentView.addSubview(widget)
          widget.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
              customContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widget.topAnchor),
              customContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widget.bottomAnchor),
              customContentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widget.leftAnchor),
              customContentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widget.rightAnchor)
        ])
      }
}


class SmallWidget: UIView { ... }

class ClientsTopWidgetView: SmallWidget {
    .....
    override func updateWidget() {
        super.updateWidget()
        models = []
        service.runOneDashboard(widgetDashboardId: model.widgetDashboardId, startDate: model.startDate, endDate: model.endDate) { result in
            self.dropDownPeriod.model = self.model
           self.getSortedClients(result)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
               self.activityIndicator.stop()
        }
    }
    ....
}
```